# regular express issue with 1 character string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am allowing only `alpha-numeric`, `_` & `-` values in string and removing all other characters. Its working fine but when string size 1 character (does not matter its `alphabet` or `numeric` or `_` or `-`), I got empty value instead of single charter.

Here is sample code

```
$str = 1;
$str = preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]$/', '', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

or

```
$str = 'a';
$str = preg_replace('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]$/', '', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

I have tested this multiple versions of [PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b79160f128090700f429c1e7642d45a0e8cf1d01) as well

Comment: You might want to remove `^` and `$` and use `'/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/'` (a negated character class) if you want to remove those chars you do not want  anywhere in a string.

Comment: After removing `^` & `$` result is [same](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/88dedb603e457321e56d7f2a9ea73e7ee4190f8b)

Comment: I meant `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_-]/', '', $str)`, => `string(1) "a"`

Comment: What is expected? You are replacing alpha numerical characters with nothing so an empty string is what I'd expect. Maybe use `preg_match` instead

Comment: I got it, Thanks @WiktorStribiżew +1 for your help :)

Comment: If that works, you may also use `preg_replace('/[^\w-]+/', '', $str)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes `\w-` looks better :)

Comment: An alternative approach could be http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php and `str_replace(array('-', '_'), '', $string)`. If you just need to verify string contents.

Comment: @user3783243 how to remove other values using `ctype-alnum`? Any example?

Comment: Don't you just want to validate a string does/doesn't have a certain set of characters?

Comment: @user3783243 Yes, I want to remove other characters. I have updated my question make it clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing any chars other than ASCII letters, digits, `_` and `-` anywhere inside the string. You need to remove anchors and convert the positive character class into a negated one:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w-]+/', '', $str);
```

See the [PHP demo online](https://ideone.com/GYynwc) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gvX20U/1).

**Details**

- `[^` - start of a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

  - `\w` - a word char: letter, digit or `_`
  - `-` - a hyphen
- `]` - end of the character class
- `+` - a quantifier: 1 or more repetitions.

Comment: How can I allow other language words like from URDU or HINDI. The above regex also removing other languages word. For example `گیت` or `न सह ब त क`

Comment: @Hassaan Try `'/[^\w\p{M}-]+/u'`.

Comment: Can you please explain what is `\p{M}`? like you done in answer

Comment: @Hassaan `\p{M}` matches any diacritics. `\w` matches just some of them when `u` modifier is on. `\w` with `u` modifier matches any base letters and digits and more.